# While Loop in Newton-Raphson C not working

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float f(float x);
float df(float x);

void main()
{
    float x0, x1, maxerror, error, g, e1, e2, e3;
    printf("NEWTON-RAPHSON PROGRAM \n\n");
    printf("Enter x0 : ");
    scanf("%f",&x0);
    printf("Enter allowed error (in percentage): ");
    scanf("%f", &maxerror);
while(error>maxerror){
    g=f(x0)/df(x0);
    x1=x0-g;
    printf("x1 : %.6f",x1);
    e1=x1-x0;
    e2=e1/x1;
    e3=abs(e2);
    error=e3*100;
    printf("error : %.6f",error);
    x0=x1;
    }
}

float f(float x)
{
    return pow(x,2)+3*x+2;      
}

float df(float x)
{
    return 2*x+3;               
}
```

can someone tell me why the 'while' loop doesn't work? It only asks until the allowed error row and then the program ended. There is also a runtime error with "NZEC" code.

Comment: what is the initial `error` value ? you didn't initialized it. Also `pow()` doesn't return a float, it returns double.

Answer (score 3):

`while(error>maxerror){`

The while loop here is not working because `error>maxerror` is not giving true,that is because you have not initialized the `error`(will have value 0.0f)and the `maxerror`is greater at the time when it reaches to condition inside the while loop,you can initialize it when declaring it like:

`float error=22.42`

or can take input through user like:

`scanf("%f", &error);`

Comment: Reading the uninitialized `error` is undefined behavior (not `0f`).